Loading an SQL dump is slow
note: I initially asked this question on stackoverflow, but was told superuser would be a better place for it. I was then made aware of the existence of dba.stackexchange, which seems like the right place for this.
I'm having performance issues while loading an sql dump into a new schema on my development machine: Creating the dump is quite fast (around 30s) but loading it back in takes more than 10 minutes.
My use case doesn't actually require a dump, I just need to clone one database (/schema ?), on the same server, as fast as possible. Doing a dump & load is simply the only way I've found to do that for now.
Here's what I'm doing so far:
mysqldump --opt MY_DATABASE > ~/my-db-dump.sql
mysql MY_NEW_DATABASE < ~/my-db-dump.sql

(I'll eventually combine these two steps, but this helps me see what part takes time, and allows inspecting the generated SQL)
The dump is 300MB, and contains the statements I would expect from the --opt flag:

UNIQUE_CHECKS=0
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
DISABLE KEYS

etc...
I've also tried increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size and disabling innodb_doublewrite, without success:
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name           | Value       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 17179869184 |
| innodb_doublewrite      | OFF         |
+-------------------------+-------------+

I asked a colleague to try loading my dump on his computer, and that took 40 seconds so I am pretty sure the issue is not on the dump side. We have essentially the same values in sql VARIABLES, apart from version_compile_machine (x86_64 vs aarch64), and a few timestamps, process IDs and file paths.
What might explain the difference between the two ? Could it be only caused by the different devices ?

Edit: As requested in a comment, here are the results of a disk benchmark.
                        KDiskMark (3.1.4): https://github.com/JonMagon/KDiskMark
                    Flexible I/O Tester (fio-3.28): https://github.com/axboe/fio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* MB/s = 1,000,000 bytes/s [SATA/600 = 600,000,000 bytes/s]
* KB = 1000 bytes, KiB = 1024 bytes

[Read]
Sequential   1 MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):  3567.022 MB/s [   3483.4 IOPS] <  2267.76 us>
Sequential   1 MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):  1117.216 MB/s [   1091.0 IOPS] <   917.91 us>
    Random   4 KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   970.079 MB/s [ 242519.8 IOPS] <   131.70 us>
    Random   4 KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    54.364 MB/s [  13591.2 IOPS] <    72.96 us>

[Write]
Sequential   1 MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):  3176.464 MB/s [   3102.0 IOPS] <  2256.61 us>
Sequential   1 MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   746.099 MB/s [    728.6 IOPS] <  1115.53 us>
    Random   4 KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   925.396 MB/s [ 231349.2 IOPS] <   136.67 us>
    Random   4 KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    72.096 MB/s [  18024.0 IOPS] <    52.80 us>

Profile: Default
   Test: 1 GiB (x5) [Measure: 5 sec / Interval: 5 sec]
   Date: 2024-11-18 10:29:32
     OS: ubuntu 22.04 [linux 6.8.0-48-generic]

I've also tried copying the entire /var/lib/mysql (with 4 other similarly sized databases). Using cp, that took less than 5 seconds (I suspect there's some weird optimisation going on there). Using the file explorer, it took 33s.


model: Dell XPS 15
cpu: 13th Gen intel i7
RAM: 32 GiB
Storage: 1T nvme ssd


you should read first https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html  and see if the buffer size is ok

My use case doesn't actually require a dump, I just need to clone one database (/schema ?) are you familiar that you can dump the schema only without the data ? Dumping Table Definitions and Content Separately

Thank you Ergest Basha, I am aware of that, but I actually do need the data as well. The reason I mentionned "schema" is that I've seen a lot of people use the term "database" to refer to the mysql server, which contain multiple schemas, each with their own data

Thank you @nbk. As mentionned, I already increased my innodb_buffer_pool_size quite significantly, without noticeable improvement. I'll check the value is a multiple of  innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances as soon as I get a chance, but I doubt this will make a difference: the doc states that the buffer pool size is adjusted to the nearest value, and my increase was large enough that it should not be rounded down to the same value.

It could certainly be caused by the difference of the two devices. Operating system, storage interface, other processes competing for resources, can all degrade performance. You might even have a faulty storage drive or faulty storage controller. It would be interesting to run a disk benchmark, independent of MySQL, to compare your machine's I/O performance to your colleague's.

300 mb are not realy great, so as bill already said, you should check if there problem with the system. As alternative, you could think about replication

Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question with the results of a disk benchmark. It looks to me like the IO should be fast enough, but I might be missing something...
@nbk thanks. If I understand correctly, replication implies keeping the replicas up to date with each other while it's being written to. If that's the case, replication doesn't fit my needs: I'm trying to create "branches" of the database, on demand.

Can you also post the time backup and restore takes, also how many idexes ou have etc, there are many factors that can be causing the problem, but for that we must understand what you define as slow

Do you mean how long a mysqldump and restore takes ? I've mentioned in the question that the dump takes around 30 seconds but loading the dump takes more than 10 minutes, while on a colleague's machine the same operation takes about 30 seconds (using the same dump file, on a docker image built from the same dockerfile)

Are there any other differences between your machine and your colleague's machine? E.g. MySQL version, Linux version, storage type, filesystem type, other processes competing for I/O resources?

@bastiengirschig yes how long takes the dump and the restore more or minus

It sounds like your storage has bad QD1 performance for writes which causes every change to the database to wait a lot for sync to be ACID compatible. This is pretty common and is expected if you have anything else but Intel Optane storage or RAID hardware with BBU (battery backup unit) to allow near instantaneous sync after write operations.
If your whole database is used for just this dump (that is, the same database server is not serving any other data worth preserving) you can run MySQL server without sync and get a huge boost to performance. However, note that in case of MySQL crash or OS level crash, you may lose the whole database. Assuming you're not running any real data except loading the dump in, this should be safe because you can always start from the beginning if the whole database is lost.
See following for details:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

Basically you can run the MySQL server with --innodb-flush-method=nosync and --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0 and you should see a huge boost in write performance. If you're running the server via systemd, it may be easier to change the MySQL config instead of trying to pass the suitable command line arguments to the server.
After the loading of dump is completed successfully, you can stop the server and restart it with normal config to return to ACID compatible behavior. The sync config matters only in case of MySQL or OS level crash (or abnormal shutdown in any other way).

You can use fio to verify if the performance of your storage is bad. When you're entering new data into the database, you basically have mixed 4KB random read/write QD 1 with sync: https://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance/991311#991311

Thanks! This reduced the un-dumping time to about 3 minutes! It's still longer than I would have hoped, but this is getting close enough that I don't think I'll be able to get better results on my machine.
I think it's safe to use those because this is not a production database, and the idea is to have plenty of copies of the db, so if one fails it should be easy to rollback to a fairly recent version.

If you want to get it faster, try running iostat -tmxyz 5 during data reload and look at the device utilization (%util). If that is near 100% (due the way iostat works values above 95% practically means the device is fully saturated already) you have found your bottleneck. Another option is to look at vmstat -SM 5 output and look at the wa column (percentage of the time used to wait for some IO device) and sy (time spent by the kernel) vs us (time spent in user mode, MySQL if your system is otherwise idle). Also look at swap si which should be zero if you have enough RAM.
